# NSTableView bindings how to add a row

Tags: cocoa, binding, nstableview, addition

I'm working on a application with the this interface (sorry the language is Dutch):

http://www.flickr.com/photos/pluueer/5756159100/

The Add function (incl. the four NSTextFields) under the NSTableView are to moved to a sheet someday, but for now this is fine. I've set up bindings according to a tutorial (http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000080.php), but the tutorial doesn't supply how to add rows in the way I want to (just adds an empty row which you need to edit in the NSTableView).

I've got a connection between the 'Voeg toe' (Dutch for 'Add') button and the Array Controller. But after clicking I get the message:

```
2011-05-28 23:37:56.149 Hop Calc[4345:a0f] -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: number of objects (0) not equal to number of keys (4)
```

It makes sense, because I've not implemented anything for adding rows, but I just don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Add a row to the table" is the wrong way to think of it. Your table represents a collection and a controller provides the information to the table, mediating between the table (view) and the collection (model). Since you mentioned bindings, the collection is likely managed by an NSArrayController. So you want to add a new object (of the kind your array controller manages) to the array controller's content array.

Simplest way: Connect the Add button to the -add: action of the NSArrayController. It'll add an empty row.

If you want more control, connect the Add button to your own custom action in some controller. That action will create an instance of whatever's represented by your array controller, prepopulate it (or whatever you want to do), then, using an outlet it holds to your NSArrayController, will call the array controller's -addObject: method to add the object (the possibly a -rearrangeObjects call to get the array controller to re-sort its contents).

Comment: Yeah I meant the ArrayController :)

I reintroduced the methods I had before adding bindings. I can tell they objects are added to the array, but I can't seem to force a refresh of the TableView. How can I do that?

Comment: How are you adding the objects? If you're adding them directly to the content array (as in, not using the array controller's methods), you're "doing it behind the array controller's back" so it doesn't see the updates. Don't add objects directly to the array the array controller controls; use NSArrayController's -addObject: (and related insert/remove) so the array controller "knows" its content array changed.

Comment: That is, "force a refresh of the table view" is also not the right way to think about it. The table view will be notified by the controller, as it should be, when a change occurs.

Comment: Yeah I am adding them straight into the array. Already read that it's behind the back of the array controller. Now I need to figure out how to do it.

Comment: ... I told you twice. :-) Once in the last paragraph of my answer and once again in my first comment above. Use NSArrayController's -addObject: method to add objects "the right way".

Comment: Yeah I know, thanks for helping me out btw. I'm Googling for an example, but can't seem to find any.

Comment: NSDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; [myArrayController addObject:dict];